# How to increase maximum user connections in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2

I am getting error "user has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 30)".

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Just run the grep command to find the mysql configuration file

```
$ grep -r "max_user_connections" /etc/mysql
```

It will point the configuration files, here you can change the value whatever you want.

> e.g) max_user_connections = 100

After that we need to restart the mysql server.

**Method 2:**

You can change the `MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS` value by run grant mysql command, in this way we can change the value to specific user and host.

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'localhost' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 10;
```

Comment: By following Method 1 I am getting error: grep: /etc/mysql: No such file or directory

Comment: By following Method 2 I am getting error: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: method1: try this `grep -r "max_user_connections" /etc/`

Comment: How to restart mysql server (any command)